# Regex multiple values

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Looking for a simple regex to be used in Google Analytics as a filter in customized channels to capture multiple values as part of a URL.

For example:

```
www.abc.com/fruit/apple/
www.abc.com/fruit/banana/
www.abc.com/fruit/pear/
www.abc.com/fruit/strawberry/
```

If I just want to capture apple, banana and pear, I thought a simple `apple|banana|pear` or `(apple|banana|pear)` would do the trick, but it doesn't.

What is missing?

Comment: Why doesn't that work? What happens? What do you expect?

Comment: What pattern do you see ?[.](https://regex101.com/r/T3umft/1/)

Comment: What is your *exact* regex? Which GA report are you using it in?

Comment: Did you also mean to include "strawberry" in that as well?

Comment: Are you looking to match them as whole words? `(^|\W)(apple|banana|pear)(\W|$)`

Comment: @nyuen Using the Customised Channel Groupings report

Comment: @ArinMauk No, I don't want to include strawberry, just the other 3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am keen to apply the regex in the Custom Channel Groupings report to redefine channels. In my case: some URLs that are being classified as (Other) should fall into email. When applying your regex in the customised Email group (Landing Page URL - matches regex- first channel in the order), the URLs are still in the (Other) group. I have reached the limit of 20 conditions already, the 19 remaining conditions include Landing Page URL - contains and when apply apple, banana or pear under these non-regex conditions, they all fall into the desired email channel

Comment: `matches regex` - try `.*(apple|banana|pear).*` to see if the whole string match is required. Although docs do not assume that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it is working now! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already did. Again, many thanks!

Comment: @razkal: No, there is no green tick to the left of my answer. Once you do it, you will get +2 rep pts

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it, done and dusted! (sorry, newbie here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `matches regex` option, the pattern seems to be anchored. So, you need to enclose the whole alternation group with `.*`:

```
.*(apple|banana|pear).*
```

To match these words as whole words, use

```
(.*\W|^)(apple|banana|pear)(\W.*|$)
```

where `(.*\W|^)` matches any 0+ chars as many as possible and then a non-word char (`.*\W`), OR (`|`) the start of string (`^`). `$` matches the end of string.

Comment: I have been trying to run the exact same thing for numeric values, however, it doesn't work for me. how can I search 123 and 456 values using matches regex?

Comment: @emily.mi Maybe you want digit boundaries, `(.*[^0-9]|^)(123|456)([^0-9].*|$)`

Comment: super awkward, still it returns nothing. when I check 123 or 456 individually it works, but when I try to combine with | (pipe) , it doesn't show values